# CDK AppSync DynamoDB Resolver Query with Expression and Expression Values

Tags: aws-cdk, dynamodb-queries

I am frustrated that there is nothing in the documentation about how to achieve this. In **Cloudformation** I can do the following:

```yaml
rExampleResolver:
  Type: "AWS::AppSync::Resolver"
  Properties:
    ApiId: !GetAtt rGraphQLApi.ApiId
    TypeName: "Items"
    FieldName: "getItems"
    DataSourceName: !GetAtt rTableDataSource.Name
    RequestMappingTemplate: |
      {
        "version" : "2017-02-28",
        "operation" : "Query",
        "query" : {
            "expression": "itemId = :itemId",
            "expressionValues" : {
                ":conversationId" : {
                    "S" : "${context.source.itemId}"
                }
            }
        },
        "index": "itemId-index"
      }
    ResponseMappingTemplate: |
      $util.toJson($context.result.items)
```

I'm trying to do the exact same thing in **CDK V2** with the following code:

```ts
const resolver = tableDataSource.createResolver({
  typeName: 'Query',
  fieldName: 'getItems',
  requestMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.dynamoDbQuery(
        KeyCondition.eq('itemId', ':itemId'),
        'itemId-index',
  ),
  responseMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.dynamoDbResultList(),
});
```

Where am I supposed to provide the `expressionValues`?

Comment: Try using `MappingTemplate.fromString`, you can pass any template you want this way.